# Why does Ubuntu updater want to install apache2-bin when updating to 18.04?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, apache2, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. I've tried to run

```
do-release-upgrade --devel
```

and suddenly have found that it wants to install **apache2-bin** among other new packages in order to upgrade to 18.04. I can't understand why it's needed.

My machine doesn't have apache installed but `/etc/apache2` directory exists and contains the only file `conf-available/javascript-common.conf`.
I don't know how it could appeared, maybe I installed apache previously and removed it later, but Synaptic shows apache2-* package as not installed (without any remaining conf files).

UPDATE: After running rdepends as suggested in comments I've found that **gnome-user-share** suggests **apache2-bin**, also it suggests **libapache2-mod-dnssd** which is also listed for install by the release upgrader.

Comment: Are you really asking for an explanation of apt's dependency logic? Did you try running an rdepends of apache2 to see what you might have installed? Did you review the upgrade logs? Or are you asking for something else (like advice)?

Comment: What's the output of `aptitude why apache2-bin` and `apt-cache redepends apache2-bin`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster their output shows that besides libapache* and apache* packages and special tools apache2-bin is rdependent on gnome-user-share. More interesting, it only suggests it (and libapache2-mod-dnssd).

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *complete, verbatim* command output listings? I can't make much of the bits and pieces that you gave me. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I didn't  manage to edit the question, SO always refuses my edit with "An error occurred submitting the edit".  I'm only able to give a pastebin link https://pastebin.com/8kGxrnxx

Comment: Hmm… if the issue with the AU site persists tomorrow and after log-out, browser restart and log-in, please file a bug report on [Meta] or, if the same issue occurs on other Stack Exchange sites too, on [Meta.SE].

Comment: Based on https://askubuntu.com/a/506185/175814 can you please try to run `do-release-upgrade` with the option `-m server` or to (temporarily) add `APT::Install-Recommends "0";` and `APT::Install-Suggests "0";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster _-m server_ is also trying to install apache2-bin. File /etc/apt/apt.conf doesn't exist

Comment: If `/etc/apt/apt.conf` doesn't exist you can create it with the aforementioned content.